# How to Express datetime higher or lower than 30 days django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

how can i Express this in django : the difference between last dateins and today is more than 30 days. this is my model

```
class Suivre(models.Model):


dateins=models.DateTimeField()
```

somthing like
a=Suivre.objects.filter()

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# not yet 30 days
Survive.objects.filter(deteins__gt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30))

# 30 days or more
Survive.objects.filter(deteins__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30))
```